# How to get an InputStream representing one file in a ZipInputStream

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have the following situation:

I am getting a Zip File sent over the network in the Form of a Byte Array. I don't want to save that file locally, but instead target an individual file in that archive and import it into my solution as an InputStream.

Thus far, I have managed to get to the point where I can identify the correct ZipEntry. However, from here all the Zip-tutorials continue by reading the entry by its file name, which naturally does not work in my case since the zip file does not exist locally.

```
private void InputStream getReqifInputStreamFrom(byte[] reqifzFileBytes){
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqifzFileBytes);
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

    while (zipEntry != null) {
        String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
        if (fileName.endsWith(REQIF_FILE_SUFFIX)) {
            return ???;
        }
        zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
}
```

So, what can I do at that point to return an InputStream that represents exactly the one file that the ZipEntry represents at that point? I have considered just returning the zipInputStream, but since I don't know exactly how that one works I'm afraid that doing so would also include all files that are still in the stream after that file to be returned as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're virtually there. Try

```
    private InputStream getReqifInputStreamFrom(byte[] reqifzFileBytes) throws IOException {
        InputStream result = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqifzFileBytes);
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

        while (zipEntry != null) {
            String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(REQIF_FILE_SUFFIX)) {
                result = zipInputStream;
                break;
            }
            zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: But doesn't that have the problem that the returned stream may still have additional files? Say for example, the file I am searching for is the second of three files in the archive, won't the returned stream contain both the second and the third file, or how does this work?

Comment: That certainly would be an issue, but I assumed that since you were doing it that way, you were looking for one. You can't have a method return more than once ;) You'd need to totally rethink if there were more than one entry. First thing that springs to mind: read them there and then and maybe return `List<byte[]>`

Comment: No, I'm just looking for one entry. I guess I'm just confused about how that stream thing works here. Say, you have a ZipInputStream that contains three Files, A, B and C, so I'll represent that as Stream[A,B,C]. I effectively want file B. The way I understand it, the stream moves forward one index at ever getNextEntry, so when it's at B it would look like Stream[B,C]. If I return that at this point, then am I not actually returning Stream[B,C]? Because what I want this function to return would be only Stream[B]. Or is it that anything I use the stream for automatically only takes the 1. entr?

Comment: > Or is it that anything I use the stream for automatically only takes the 1. entr? < afaik, yes (I'm not 100% sure myself how it works). I think it has an 'entry pointer' which would have to be advanced to get Stream[C] by calling 'next entry' (which you won't do)